# Не срабатывает GET запрос

Tags: html, jquery, get

Есть структура GET, с помощью которой хочу отправить значение параметра, при переходе на другую страницу. Значение не передается. Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему. Что не так? Уже в отчаяние :-(

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

$('.search_me_tag').on('click', function () {
      
var tag = $(this).attr('rel');

        $.get({
          url: '/blog',
          data: tag, 
          success: function( data ) { 
            $('.search_edit').val(data);
          }, 
          dataType: "text" 
        });
        
 });
 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="search_me_tag" href="/blog" rel="test">Блог</a>
```

Comment: У вас обработчиком запроса является /blog/index.php ?

Comment: нет, не является

Comment: грубо говоря, мне необходимо с одной странице на другую перенести значение параметра тега (без AJAX), средствами GET, или же альтернативным решением.

Comment: если в рамках одного домена, то запишите все, что вам надо в `localStorage` и при переходе на целевую страницу прочтите.

Comment: я уже так и сделал. Все работает, только не всегда, почему-то.